# React context to change components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm building a dashboard that displays multiple graphs on the main page.
A graph has additional filter functions (change min max). The graph is in one component with the control elements and the display for the min/max is in another component.
I want to change the Min/Max display when the graph has changed (i.e. after switching the control element)

Currently my components look like this:

```
 graph.js
 var controllElements = (<button onClick={() => this.minmax('min)>..
                         <button onClick={() => this.minmax('max)>)
 return(
  <div>
      {graph}
      {controllElements}
  </div>)


minmaxview.js

return(
<div>{value}
</div>)
```

I do not use redux in this project and it is not possible to use it in this project.

So I thought I would use the react context api but have no experience with it.

In the end, it should look like this.
If button min is clicked (graph.js) => Change value in minmaxview.js

My question is now. Can I use react context for this? If possible, are there any good examples? Or does anyone have another solution?

If necessary through sessions (Probably not possible due to an infinite loop in the compUpdate when setting state)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like below to utilize React Context API's Provider/Consumer concept. Clearly it will need to be tailored within your app on however it is structured but based on minimal example that you provided, I tried my best to come closely to do Provider/Consumer psuedo react-code.

```js
//graph.js
 export const GraphContext = React.createContext(0);  // asuming default for min/max is 0
 
 var controllElements = (<button onClick={() => this.minmax('min)>..
                         <button onClick={() => this.minmax('max)>)
 return(
  <div>
      {graph}
      <GraphContext.Provider value={this.state.graphValuesObject}>
        {/* Assume minmax function will update graphValuesObject that can be passed around */}
        {controllElements}
      </GraphContext.Provider>
  </div>)


//minmaxview.js
import GraphContext from './graph.js';

return (
  <GraphContext.Consumer>
     {graphValuesObject => <div>{value}</div> }
  </GraphContext.Consumer>
)
```

More info here: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html